# How to enable event handlers after using $("#id").off();

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a search form with a dropdown selection which enables user to search by a specific column.Here's my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/home/search');?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
<div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:150px" >  
    <select class="form-control pull-left" name="searchby" id="searchby" >
        <option class="label">- Search by -</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
        <option value="date">Date</option>
    </select> 
</div>    
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-left:10px">
    <div class="input-group date col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search " name="key_key" id="key_key" required /> 
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-md" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also used datepicker. Whenever the value of the `<select>` tag is **date**, I trigger the **datepicker**.. And to disable it I think, I have used something like this `$("#id").off();` But the problem is, when the value after removing event handlers  is **date** again, the datepicker don't pop-up. To further understand it, here's my jquery code :

```
$('#searchby').on('change', function() {
if(this.value=="date"){
     $("#key_key").on();
     $('#key_key').datepicker();

}
else{
    // $('#key_key').datepicker("disable");
    $("#key_key").off();
}
})
```

Can anyone help me this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: once you use `.off()`, you will have to re-register the handlers again

Comment: How am I going to re-register the handlers again? I tried `.on()` just thinking that it might be the solution but it didn't work. And I actually don't know if there's really a `.on()` function.. I just tried it..

Comment: [Yes there is](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @D4V1D, I didn't notice that I've been using it already.. Maybe because of the parameters inside it that I didn't notice that is already an `.on()` function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/9hugw0b7/) fiddle. It works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#key_key').datepicker();
 $('#searchby').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == "date") {            
            $('#key_key').datepicker();
        } else {
            $('#key_key').datepicker("destroy");
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: thanks for the idea.. I used ` $('#key_key').datepicker("remove");` instead.. I don't know but `"destroy"` didn't work on me.. Maybe because I used bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: May be. I didn't include bootstrap. I used JQuery ui js and ui css.